# AsyncTask sequence is faster than parallel

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, parallel-processing

I uploaded photos using AsyncTask to Amazon S3 server. I found AsyncTask waiting one after another instead of running in parallel as default.

So, change my code to use  `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])` to run parallel. But I found it is slower than default AsyncTask sequence execution.

May I know what's wrong with that ? Because I assumed parallel must be faster. Am I wrong ?

Comment: What about upload speed in kbps? Is it the same in both cases? Multiple connections are not always faster.

Comment: I can say same speed ! I noticed uploading in parallel take more in initiation. Oh ! Probably, when they share connection, it become slow connection and take more times than sequence. Is that you mean ?

Comment: I'll give you an example: when you increase your max connection count in a torrent client by 10 the downloading speed drops significantly. Thats because much of the bandwidtch is used for managing these connections and not transfering the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is this is rather a network problem. Possible reasons are:

- Connections overhead "eats" upload bandwidtch (If there are many of these).
- Server policy may decreasing speeds when multiple connections are detected. This is very likely.

Comment: Now, I see what's happening there, @soulreaver thanks for you explanation. Can you share me how to upload image faster ?

Comment: You wrote than both (single & multiple) conntection uploads are the same speed. In that case I would check if the upload speed is not restricted by the server. If yes, there's nothing you can do.